# How to launch Apps, from my App, with a custom parameter so I can check whether the app was launched by me?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, launching-application, nsapplication

I'm working on this app that launches other apps. I'm listening to app launches using:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(appLaunched:) name:NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification
 object:nil];
```

And I launch them using (Mail is just an example):

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"lalalala"], NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments, nil];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplicationAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/Applications/Mail.app"] options:NSWorkspaceLaunchWithoutActivation configuration:dict error:nil];
```

I did some research, and I saw that you can send an argument when you launch an app (that's why I used the var `dict` in the code above), but I'm having an issue with this: even using `NSWorkspaceLaunchWithoutActivation`, the Mail.app is launched and becomes focused with a new composing window. I don't know why it's doing that.


Another thing, if I manage to successfully send a custom argument without focusing the app, how can I check if the app was launched by me (check if the argument is there)?
PS: I'm looking for App Store-ready methods.

Comment: You cannot check another app's launch args unless that app provides an API to do so just like the command line.  The argument is the thing you see in main.m of every Cocoa app template. It's I'd standard POSIX argc and argv for main()

Comment: Can you get a process ID back after launch and use it to query later?

Comment: NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments is not available for sandboxed apps: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsworkspacelaunchconfigurationarguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the timestamp (UTC) together with the app name you started to your server or a local file if possible.

Then you can track it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd try `NSWorkspaceLaunchAndHide` if `NSWorkspaceLaunchWithoutActivation` isn't "working".  Not ideal, no.. but a kludge...

Secondly... here's a "full, running example" that does the trick..

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
NSString *psAUX(NSString*grep) {    
    FILE *read_f; char buff[BUFSIZ+1]; int char_rd; NSString *res, *cmnd;
    memset(buff, '\0', sizeof(buff)); 
    cmnd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/bin/ps aux|grep -i %@",grep];
    read_f = popen(cmnd.UTF8String, "r");
    if (read_f == NULL) return nil;
    char_rd = fread(buff, sizeof(char), BUFSIZ, read_f);
    if (!char_rd) return nil; 
    return res = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buff], pclose(read_f), res;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { @autoreleasepool {         
    NSString* secretStr; NSURL *mailURL; NSDictionary *cfg; NSWorkspace *ws; NSApplication.sharedApplication;
    secretStr = @"TAMPAX";
    mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Applications/Mail.app"];
    cfg  = @{NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments:@[secretStr]};
    ws = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace;
    [ws launchApplicationAtURL:mailURL options:0 configuration:cfg error:nil];
    fprintf(stderr,"%s", 

        [psAUX(@"Mail.app") containsString:secretStr] 
      ? "You ARE Mail's baby's daddy!" 
      : "Hands off, she's NOT yours!");

[NSApp run];  }   }
```

`NSLog` -> `You ARE Mail's baby's daddy!`

Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try it later. Btw, is that app store-ready?

Comment: I don't see anything that would be overtly offensive about it...  It's basically just a different way of calling `NSTask`.

Comment: `sh: /bin/ps: Operation not permitted`

Comment: any idea how the prevent getting the 'are you sure you want to open the application' dialogue for my helper? http://i.stack.imgur.com/TQCcf.png

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Task using NSTask. With NSTask you can set arguments as well as some environment variables to app so that you can check if it is launched by you or by someone else.

Here is the sample code sniffet to do so:

```
NSTask* taskApp = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[taskApp setLaunchPath:@"App path goes here"];
[taskApp setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Arg1",@"arg2", nil]];
[taskApp setEnvironment: [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment]];
[taskApp launch];
```